# Is it possible to jump to the next wrapped line in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, if there're many lines in a file, I can use `hjkl` to navigate, I can just press `j` to jump to the next line.

However, if I am processing a very long line of text, I use `set wrap` to wrap it into many lines. It is still one single line, but visually looks like many line to a vim user.

In such a case, if one line of text is wrapped into many lines, it is possible to jump between wrapped fake-lines instead of pressing `h` or `l` to jump by characters or pressing `w` to jump by words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motion for that is `gj`. (Or `g<any other direction>`.)

```
gj      or                  *gj* *g<Down>*
g<Down>         [count] display lines downward.  |exclusive| motion.
            Differs from 'j' when lines wrap, and when used with
            an operator, because it's not linewise.
```